# How to combine multiple images horizontally and vertically using ffmpeg

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

I'm attempting to create a script that can stitch together images side by side. These images are basically letters that I want to create words with (think of those ransom letters in Hollywood movies with randomly cut out letters from magazines). I need to specifically use these images, so I don't want ffmpeg to type out some words into images itself. I've seen some similar answers using `hstack` and `tile` filter complexes but those didn't work for me. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i h.png -i e.png -i l.png -i l.png -i o.png -filter_complex tile=5x1 test.png
```

For this one, -pattern_type didn't exist as an option (I'm using ffmpeg 4.2 on Windows), so I removed it and the result was 1 letter and black space for the rest.

```
ffmpeg -y -i h.png -i e.png -i l.png -i l.png -i o.png -filter_complex hstack test.png
```

For this one, the result was 2 letters side by side, and then black space for the rest.

All of my images are of the same height and variable width. Is there a command that can achieve this?

Comment: You have to add the `inputs` option in the hstack filter because the default is `inputs=2`, and you have to tell hstack which inputs you want to stack. See "Example 3: Three videos or images" in duplicate link.

Comment: @llogan Thank you, I completely missed that response and that works perfectly!